# src attribute of script tag in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

Can i use following line of code in phonegap?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js" ></script>
```

where src is pointing to javascript api of skydrive.
Is it possible to connect to servers using src in phonegap?
Or is it similar to  files loaded to browser from local filesystem which does not work if the above line is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is it similar to files loaded to browser from local filesystem which does not work if the above line is there.

It is exactly the same. You aren't loading the PhoneGap application over HTTP or HTTPS, so you can't use a scheme relative URI to load resources available via those schemes.

Be explicit and use `http://js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js` or `https://js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js`.